# How to calculate the probability of the difference between two negative binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This was asked here: [Understanding the solution of a probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960219/understanding-the-solution-of-a-probability-question)

> Automobile policies are separated into two groups: low-risk and
> high-risk. Actuary Rahul examines low-risk policies, continuing until
> a policy with a claim is found and then stopping. Actuary Toby follows
> the same procedure with high-risk policies. Each low-risk policy has a
> 10% probability of having a claim. Each high-risk policy has a 20%
> probability of having a claim, The claim statuses of policies are
> mutually independent. Calculate the probability that Actuary Rahul
> examines fewer policies than Actuary Toby.

There were various solutions that I understand. However, I wanted to know why it could not be calculated this way:

Calculate the mean of each distribution.

$ \mu$ for Rahul: $ \frac {.9}{.1} = 9 $   Variance for Rahul: $ \frac {.9}{.1^2} = 90 $

$ \mu$ for Toby : $ \frac {.8}{.2} = 4 $   Variance for Toby : $ \frac {.8}{.2^2} = 20 $

The joint variance is 110 -> joint standard deviation is 10.488

Expected difference of policies between Rahul and Toby is 9 - 4 = 5.

Therefore, the probability that Rahul examines fewer is the probability that the difference is 0 or less. This should be the probability that the difference is less than 5/10.488 (Z = -.4767) standard deviations.

With a z-score calculator this corresponds to a probability of .31679.

The actual answer was .2857. Why the discrepancy in answers? Why is it inappropriate to calculate joint variance and find the probability of the difference of the expected values of each distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your calculations:

- Your z-score calculation assumes that the difference between the number of polices examined by Toby and Rahul is [*normally distributed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (at least to a good approximation), and this isn't the case.
- The probability mass functions of the numbers of policies examined by the actuaries have the form $\ p(1-p)^{n-1}\ $ for $\ n=1,2,\dots\ $ rather than $\ np(1-p)^n\ $ for $\ n=1,2,\dots\ $, or $\ p(1-p)^n\ $ for $\ n=0,1,\dots\ $, and hence a mean of $\ \frac{1}{p}\ $, rather than $\ \frac{1-p}{p}\ $ (although this turns out not to affect the calculation of $\ Z\ $).

If $\ R\ $ and $\ T\ $ are the numbers of policies examined by Rahul and Toby, respectively, the the probability mass functions of $\ R\ $ and $\ T\ $ are given by
\begin{align}
P(R=n)&=(1-p_1)^{n-1}p_1\\
P(T=n)&=(1-p_2)^{n-1}p_2\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ p_1=0.1\ $ and $\ p_2=0.2\ $.  The probability that Rahul examines fewer policies than Toby is given by
$$
P(R<T)=\frac{p_1(1-p_2)}{1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}=\frac{2}{7}\approx0.2857\ .
$$ Your calculation of the probability from the $\ Z$-value, on the other hand, gives you the probability that $\ X\le Z\ ,\ $ *for $\ X\ $ a standard normal variate*.  The large difference between the two values tells you that a normal distribution is a very poor approximation to the distribution of $\ R-T\ $.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't a geometric distribution also a negative binomial if k=1?

Comment: No. The negative binomial distribution for $\ k=1\ $ has probability mass function $\ {\color{red}n}p(1-p)^n\ $, whereas the geometric distribution has probability mass function $\ p(1-p)^{n-1}\ $ (the one we need to use here) or $\ p(1-p)^n\ $.  Nevertheless, since the difference doesn't  affect the value you get for $\ Z\ $, and I made a mistake in my calculation of the variance of $\ T\ $, my answer was not as helpful as it should have been. I've now amended it.